# PDF Data and Table Scraping to Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, ocr, screen-scraping, pdf-parsing

I'm trying to figure out a good way to increase the productivity of my data entry job.

What I am looking to do is come up with a way to scrape data from a PDF and input it into Excel.

More specifically the data I am working with is from grocery store flyers. As it stands now we have to manually enter every deal in the flyer into a database. A sample of a flyer is http://weeklyspecials.safeway.com/customer_Frame.jsp?drpStoreID=1551

What I am hoping to do is have columns for products, price, and predefined options (Loyalty Cards, Coupons, Select Variety... that sort of thing).

Any help would be appreciated, and if I need to be more specific let me know.

Comment: The bot friendly RSS feed doesn't suit your needs?  http://weeklyspecials.safeway.com/rss.jsp?drpStoreID=1551&categories=all ?

Answer (score 27):

After looking at the specific PDF **[linked to by the OP](http://weeklyspecials.safeway.com/SafewaySafeway04222015SeattleWeeklyAd/pdf/S1.pdf)**, I have to say that this is not quite displaying a typical table format.

It contains many images inside the "cells", but the cells are not all strictly vertically or horizontally aligned:

[image: Page 6 from the PDF linked in the OP]

So this isn't even a 'nice' table, but an extremely ugly and awkward one to work with...

---

Having said that, I'll have to add:

### Extracting even 'nice' tables from PDFs *in general* is extremely difficult...

Standard PDFs do not provide any hints about the *semantics* of what they draw on a page: 
the only distinction that the syntax provides is the distinctions between vector elements (lines, fills,...), images and text.

Whether any character is part of a table or part of a line or just a lonely, single character within an otherwise empty area is not easy to recognize programmatically by parsing the PDF source code.

For a background about why the ***PDF file format should never, ever be thought of as suitable for hosting extractable, structured data***, see this article:

> **[Why Updating Dollars for Docs Was So Difficult](http://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/heart-of-nerd-darkness-why-dollars-for-docs-was-so-difficult)** (ProPublica-Website)

### ...but doing so with TabulaPDF works very well!

Having said the above now let me add this:

- For an amazing open source family of tools that gets better and better from week to week for extracting tabular data from PDFs (unless they are scanned pages) -- ***contradicting what I said in my introductionary paragraphs***! -- check out ***[TabulaPDF](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula)***. See these links:

  - **[Introducing Tabula: Upload a PDF, get back tabular CSV data. Poof!](https://source.opennews.org/en-US/articles/introducing-tabula/)**
  - **[Tabula-Extractor: A Command Line Interface to Tabula](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-extractor)**
  - **[Tabula source code repository](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula)**
  - **[Tabula API (upcoming, not ready yet)](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-api)**

Tabula-Extractor is written in Ruby.
In the background it makes use of PDFBox (which is written in Java) and a few other third-party libs.
To run, Tabula-Extractor requires JRuby-1.7 installed.

---

### Installing Tabula-Extractor

I'm using the 'bleeding-edge' version of Tabula-Extractor directly from its GitHub source code repository. 
Getting it to work was extremely easy, since on my system JRuby-1.7.4_0 is already present:

```
mkdir ~/svn-stuff
cd ~/svn-stuff
git clone https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-extractor.git git.tabula-extractor
```

Included in this Git clone will already be the required libraries, so no need to install PDFBox.
The command line tool is in the `/bin/` subdirectory.

Exploring the command line options:

```
~/svn-stuff/git.tabula-extractor/bin/tabula -h

Tabula helps you extract tables from PDFs

Usage:
       tabula [options] <pdf_file>
where [options] are:
         --pages, -p <s>:   Comma separated list of ranges, or all. Examples:
                            --pages 1-3,5-7, --pages 3 or --pages all. Default
                            is --pages 1 (default: 1)
          --area, -a <s>:   Portion of the page to analyze
                            (top,left,bottom,right). Example: --area
                            269.875,12.75,790.5,561. Default is entire page
       --columns, -c <s>:   X coordinates of column boundaries. Example
                            --columns 10.1,20.2,30.3
      --password, -s <s>:   Password to decrypt document. Default is empty
                            (default: )
             --guess, -g:   Guess the portion of the page to analyze per page.
             --debug, -d:   Print detected table areas instead of processing.
        --format, -f <s>:   Output format (CSV,TSV,HTML,JSON) (default: CSV)
       --outfile, -o <s>:   Write output to <file> instead of STDOUT (default:
                            -)
       --spreadsheet, -r:   Force PDF to be extracted using spreadsheet-style
                            extraction (if there are ruling lines separating
                            each cell, as in a PDF of an Excel spreadsheet)
    --no-spreadsheet, -n:   Force PDF not to be extracted using
                            spreadsheet-style extraction (if there are ruling
                            lines separating each cell, as in a PDF of an Excel
                            spreadsheet)
            --silent, -i:   Suppress all stderr output.
  --use-line-returns, -u:   Use embedded line returns in cells. (Only in
                            spreadsheet mode.)
           --version, -v:   Print version and exit
              --help, -h:   Show this message
```

### Extracting the table which the OP wants

**I'm not even *trying* to extract this ugly table from the OP's monster PDF.** I'll leave it as an excercise to these readers who are feeling adventurous enough...

Instead, I'll demo how to extract a 'nice' table. I'll take pages 651-653 from the **[official PDF-1.7 specification](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/ISO32000/PDF32000-Adobe.pdf)**, here represented with screenshots:

[image: Pages 651-653 of the official PDF-1.7 specification]

I used this command:

```
 ~/svn-stuff/git.tabula-extractor/bin/tabula \
   -p 651,652,653 -g -n -u -f CSV            \
    ~/Downloads/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf
```

After importing the generated CSV into LibreOffice Calc, the spreadsheet looks like this:

[image: Screenshot from LibreOffice after importing the CSV]

To me this looks like the perfect extraction of a table which did spread over 3 different PDF pages. *(Even the newlines used within table cells made it into the spreadsheet.)*

---

### Update

Here is an ASCiinema screencast (which you also can **[download](https://asciinema.org/a/22761.json)** and re-play locally in your Linux/MacOSX/Unix terminal with the help of the `asciinema` command line tool), starring `tabula-extractor`:

[image: asciicast]

Comment: This answer is way too long for it's message, imho. The message as I see it: in your case it's next to impossible to extract the tabular data from the PDF. For more structured PDFs there is awesome TabulaPDF.

Comment: @Bobrovsky: Thanks very much for your hint, I'll consider it for the next time  :)  -- no thanks for your downvote though!

Comment: Reads too much like an ad

Comment: @jjc: Thanks for your excellent downvote then, dear neighbor!

Comment: thank you for your recommendation, but it sounds so hard to do.. I wish mechanize would do something like this.

Comment: @Kurt Pfeifle: Good answer. The command line options are unclear but it looks as though -r is for PDFs with ruling lines and -n is for PDFs without. Why did you choose the -n (--no-spreadsheet) option in your command?

Comment: This is an excellent answer as an introduction to the problem with extracting data from PDF and to the best tool available `tabula`. Thank you!